# Java Mail: How to Recognize New Mails

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

When I receive mails, open the inbox, and get the messages; how can I compare them to a previous array of messages, so that I know which of them I have already read?

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.put("mail.imaps.host", host);
properties.put("mail.imaps.port", "993");
Session emailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

//2) create the POP3 store object and connect with the pop server
Store emailStore = emailSession.getStore("imaps");
emailStore.connect(user,pw);

//3) create the folder object and open it
Folder emailFolder = emailStore.getFolder("INBOX");
emailFolder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
Message[] messages = emailFolder.getMessages();
```

Comment: Are sure that you need to save previous messages? You read messages from inbox as an event. So, you alway read a new message then you cann't read the same message twice.

Comment: well my app displays (some of) the mails. If i delete a mail from that list i don't want it to reappear when i refresh the folder, but i get all the mails again.
Of course i can compare date, from, subject, etc but is there a way to make sure if a Message is already contained in the messages i recieved last time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to handle this depends on exactly what your requirements are.  For example, will other applications and/or users be accessing the mailbox at the same time as your application?  Or does your application have dedicated access to the mailbox?

You can [use the SEEN flag to find messages that you haven't already read](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#getunread).

You can also save the IMAP UID for the last message you processed (and the UIDVALIDITY for the folder) to later find messages with larger UIDs.  See the [UIDFolder](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/UIDFolder.html) interface for details.

(The comments in your code talk about pop, but your code is using imap; if you ever have to use the pop3 protocol the [answers are quite different](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#newmsgs).)

Comment: tanks, that UID is, what i was looking for. I just didnt have the idea to look at the folder and the Message itself gives u only a messagenumber which can be "reassigned" if the content of the folder changes. But i guess, that UID won't be reused if the message is deleted